# loading JKS in Jar in System.setProperty

Tags: java, jar, jks

I am loading property file using `getClass.getResourceAsStream();`

I m getting jks location from property file - `"properties/JKS_FILE_NAME"`

this location will be inside the jar when deployed

now this location i set in

```
System.setProperty(
                  "javax.net.ssl.trustStore",this.KEY_STORE_LOCATION);
```

Now problem is when packaged inside JAR , this is not able to find the location and says `FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION`

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try [JAR protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/author/jar.html#jarprotocol) when referring to files in a JAR archive. The location should look something like `jar:file:/path/to/foo.jar!/path/to/jks.keystore`.